Calculating the overall value of the cell based on the dictionary in google sheets
I have a value in one cell looking something like this:
(The product name and the amount required)
[Product1] 1, [Product2] 2, [Product3] 3
As well i have a dictionary looking something like:
(Each product value)



A
B




Product1
100


Product2
125


Product3
225



Im curious to know if its possible to get the overall value of the cell's products?
So in that case i need to get a value of 1025
Honestly didnt tried much, becuase im not that familiar with google sheets.
Don't even know how to approach the problem.


You may try:
=let(Σ,index(substitute(split(tocol(split(A2,", ",)),"] ",),"[",)),
 sumproduct(ifna(vlookup(index(Σ,,1),E:F,2,)),index(Σ,,2)))



Omg! Thank you very much!
